# obj-c presentmodalviewcontroller.. Where to release

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an app that switches around to about 10 different view controllers with methods like this:

```
 -(IBAction)pg2button{
      pg2 *pg2view = [[pg2 alloc] initWithNibName: nil bundle: nil];
      pg2view.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
      [self presentModalViewController:pg2view animated:YES];
      [pg2view release];
  }
```

Where is a good place to release the current view before the next one is presented?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean release or dismiss?

Comment: I mean dismiss. When I present a new modal view from that one I need to dismiss the old one or else it hogs up memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Format your question: add at least 4 spaces before each code line.

(2) Why do you use `initWithNibName:bundle:` initializer if you pass nil as NIB name?
Just use the regular `init`.

(3) I see that you already release the view controller.
It will be released one more time (in the background) once you will dismiss it.

(4) If you've meant to ask "Where is a good place to **dismiss** the current view before the next one is presented?" then it depends on your structure.
Usually, the best approach is to add a delegate method in the original view controller, the modal view controller will call that delegate method and the original view controller will dismiss the modal one like this: `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`.

**EDIT**:
Code sample for the delegate:

```
// The protocol that your original view controller should implement
@protocol ModalViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

@required
- (void)modalViewControllerDidCancel:(UIViewController *)modalViewController;
- (void)modalViewController:(UIViewController *)modalViewController didReturnWithResult:(NSObject)result;

@end
```

This is how to implement:

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <ModalViewControllerDelegate> {

    ...

}

...

@end

@implementation MainViewController

...

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark ModalViewControllerDelegate methods

- (void)modalViewControllerDidCancel:(UIViewController *)modalViewController {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)modalViewController:(UIViewController *)modalViewController didReturnWithResult:(NSObject)result {
    // TODO: Do something with the result

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

...

@end
```

You should add the next code to your modal view controllers:

```
@interface ModalViewController1 : UIViewController {

    ...

    id<ModalViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

    ...

}

@property (assign) id<ModalViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

...

@end


@implementation ModalViewController1

@synthesize delegate;

...

- (void)cancelUserAction {

    ...

    [self.delegate modalViewControllerDidCancel:self];
}

@end
```

Don't forget also to set the delegate property to self (from MainViewController) once you create the modal view controller...

Comment: Thanks. It seems I do need to go the delegate route but i'm having a hard time understanding how to implement it because there are so many examples out there and they all seem different. Obviously i'm pretty new to Obj-c.

All of my views are presented(except the first) with the presentmodalview method, and they each have pretty much the same button menu that presents other views modally, and you can just switch between them. 
I probably have gone wrong in that I programmed it exactly how it appears visually. i.e. I think I could have used 1 or 2 view controllers instead of 9.